# How to automate the creation of a folder, and a text file within it from CSV data

Tags: applescript, automator

For each line of a delimited text file, I want to have Automator create a folder named from a field of the source file.

Then in that folder, create a text file named "file.json" with the contents being a string of data from another field of the source file.

The CSV file would have about 100 entries, and probably just two fields like

`folderName | { JSON was here }`

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know automator so well, but the following AppleScript should do what you want. Does not have much in the way of error checking.

```
try
    set src to (choose file with prompt "choose your input")
    set o to (open for access src)
    set inputStr to (read o)
    close access o
end try
set fldrOut to (choose folder with prompt "choose your output folder")

set atids to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "|"
repeat with p in (paragraphs of inputStr)
    set folderName to text item 1 of (p as string)
    set jsonString to text item 2 of (p as string)
    tell application "Finder"

        set fldr to (make new folder at fldrOut with properties {name:folderName})

    end tell
    set pth to (fldrOut as string) & folderName & ":file.json"
    set outFile to (open for access pth with write permission)
    write jsonString to outFile starting at 0
    close access outFile
end repeat
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to atids
```